# How to access urls of images and xy coordinates from the DOM. dragging related also pure js please

Tags: image, dom

How to access urls of images  and xy coordinates from the DOM.

I have a div with multiple image gifs in it.

The gifs  represent electronic components on stripboard or protoboard.
The  img gifs are generated using this code.

```
function createDiv(img)//img here original code was for creating new divs

{
alert(divnumber);//an incrementing or decrementing image array position counter
{ 
var divTag = document.createElement("img");

    divTag.id ='part'+divnumber;
    imageArray[divnumber+1]=200;//arbitrary inital x placement
    imageArray[divnumber+2]=200;//arbitrary initial y placment


    divTag.className ="dragme";

    divTag.src = imageArray[divnumber];//gif;//imageArray[i];

    document.body.appendChild(divTag);
        }
    divnumber=divnumber+3;//offset between gif url in image array

}
```

The gifs are draggable using this code. I don't fully understand drag code but it was the simplest I could find and make work.

```
//<script language="JavaScript1.2">
<!--

var ie=document.all;//if using explorer
var nn6=document.getElementById&&!document.all;//if using netscape

var isdrag=false;//are we dragging??
var x,y;
var dobj;//drag object

function movemouse(e)
{ 
  if (isdrag) //if drag istrue
  {
    dobj.style.left = nn6 ? tx + e.clientX - x : tx + event.clientX - x;
    //alert(dobj.style.left);
    dobj.style.top  = nn6 ? ty + e.clientY - y : ty + event.clientY - y;
    return false;
  }
}

function selectmouse(e) 
{
  var fobj       = nn6 ? e.target : event.srcElement;
  var topelement = nn6 ? "HTML" : "BODY";

  while (fobj.tagName != topelement && fobj.className != "dragme")
  {
    fobj = nn6 ? fobj.parentNode : fobj.parentElement;
  }

  if (fobj.className=="dragme")
  {
    isdrag = true;
    dobj = fobj;
    tx = parseInt(dobj.style.left+0);
    //alert(tx);
    ty = parseInt(dobj.style.top+0);
    x = nn6 ? e.clientX : event.clientX;
    //alert(x +'   "=y);
    y = nn6 ? e.clientY : event.clientY;
    document.onmousemove=movemouse;
    return false;
  }
}

document.onmousedown=selectmouse;//go to selectmouse when mouse down in document
document.onmouseup=new Function("isdrag=false");

//-->
```

I need to put all the gifs and x y coordinates into an array that I can save with html5 local storage.
I can save an array and recall it ok.
But I need to fill the array with urls and xy coords of draggable items.
I can't figure how to get that info from either  the dragging code or the DOM.
I think I can get that info from the dom image list but I still cant get up to speeds on all the dom details.

Can anyone tell me how to identify the gif url and xy coordinates from either the drag code or the DOM.
This is basically my last hurdle before I can comnplete the prrogram.
Many Thanks. I am mainly a cut and paste and hacking found scripts in my programming level.
Oh!! I am almost 70 and this IS NOT a homework problem!!
Thanks markE for last help.
TiMathis

After further thought I can probably dig the xy's out of the drag code but how can I determine which gif is being dragged?

Answer (score 0):

OK I can get the objects id ...alert(dobj.id) 
I should be able to use that to get other info for immage array info I need.

```
    if (fobj.className=="dragme")
      {
        isdrag = true;
        dobj = fobj;





alert(dobj.id);
        tx = parseInt(dobj.style.left+0);
        //alert(tx);
        ty = parseInt(dobj.style.top+0);
        x = nn6 ? e.clientX : event.clientX;
        //alert(x +'   "=y);
        y = nn6 ? e.clientY : event.clientY;
        document.onmousemove=movemouse;
        return false;
      }
    }
```